# Python Database update from XML only updates last record

Tags: python, xml-parsing, mysql-python

I have write a script to update stock in my mysql db, but i get only the last record from the xml updated, i'm looking through a tunnel right know and love to have a fresh pair of eyes looking at it.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
r = requests.get('http://api.edc.nl/xml/eg_xml_feed_stock.xml')

root = ET.fromstring(r.content)

for x in root.iter('product'):
    id = x.find('productid').text
    qty = x.find('qty').text


try:
    with connect(
        host="my host",
        user=input("Enter username: "),
        database="my database",
        password=getpass("Enter password: "),


    ) as connection:
        query = "UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `quantity` = " + \
            qty + " WHERE `id_product` = " + id + ";"
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            connection.commit()
            #result = cursor.fetchall()
            # for row in result:
            print(query)
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to substitute into a query, use placeholders and parameters.

Comment: Yea  working on that, learning everyday thx. But that has noting to do with this last records right? placeholders and paramaters is using this %s i thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that upates the table needs to be inside the `for` loop. Otherwise it only runs once after the loop completes, and uses the last values of the variables.

```
query = "UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `quantity` = %s WHERE `id_product` = %s"

try:
    with connect(
        host="my host",
        user=input("Enter username: "),
        database="my database",
        password=getpass("Enter password: "),
    ) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for x in root.iter('product'):
                prod_id = x.find('productid').text
                qty = x.find('qty').text
                cursor.execute(query, (qty, prod_id))
            connection.commit()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Don't use `id` as a variable, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, i have updated the script, because the id was qty and the qty was id :)